# Azure BlobStorage Connector can't connect to blob with enabled firewall

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

we are trying to connect from powerapps to blob storage using Azure Blob Storage Connector.
I have checked on which region I am in powerapps and it's Europe.
So I have whitelisted all of IP's from [this azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/limits-and-config#ip-addresses) but still no access.
[Screen Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN2dM.png)

When I disable the firewall on blob everything works fine.
There is another list of IP's that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

un-authorized message due to lack of  permissions. Try with  assigning **Storage Account specific permissions** to user.

To do this, the storage account manager should:

**1. Navigate to the container's Access Control (IAM) tab.**

**2. Click on Add**

**3. Click on Add role assignment**

**4. Assign a specific Storage Account role to the user (for example, Storage Account Contributor)**

For more details refer this documents

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-blob-storage

Comment: It's not the permission, because when I disable Storage Account firewall, connection is made from powerapps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar query, this is not a permission issue. It's a firewall issue. Moreover, the no of IPs that PowerApps have. It's not recommended to whitelist all of them.